# jumpy scroll animation with css

Tags: css, animation, footer

I've got a little CSS animation on the footer of my website that's a bit jumpy because it just starts over - how can I make it run smoothly and continuously? Thank you!

```css
footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  width: 3000%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: Bespoke C1lzphnm8n Webfont;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.slide {
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-800px);
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="slide">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://mixcloud.com/phuzzphuzzphuzz">FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE   </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: add `linear` to the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS animations, as stated here -> [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations), have a bunch of properties including the [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) which :

> specifies how a CSS animation should progress over the duration of each cycle.

`animation-timing-function` has an initial value of `ease` which causes that 'jumpy' effect you are talking about. It's a combination of `ease-out` and `ease-in` which means the animation starts slowly, then normal, then ends slowly.

If you want an animation that doesn't fluctuate in it's 'speed', then you should use `animation-timing-function: linear`.

To write your animation in one line use : `animation: slide 12s infinite linear;`, this would translate to

```
{
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-duration: 12s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

See snippet below :

```css
footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  width: 3000%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: Bespoke C1lzphnm8n Webfont;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.slide {
  animation: slide 12s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-800px);
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="slide">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://mixcloud.com/phuzzphuzzphuzz">FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE FULL SHOW HERE   </a>
</footer>
```